# Spring session scoped objects in @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring, session, scope, autowired

In spring, I have a lot of code that uses session beans defined like this:

```
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

- In my webapplication all is fine, since a session scope is
  available.
- In my JUnit tests, all is also fine since i'm using a
  `WebContextTestExecutionListener` ([link](http://code.google.com/p/java-seam-examples/source/browse/src/test/java/org/spring/jsf/app/scope/WebContextTestExecutionListener.java?r=a4948940e92926c16d69f33d4cd43ad7cd17b266)) that registers a thread
  scope for the session scope
- But when a method with `@Scheduled` is called, I get an exception since there is no
  session scope.

Now my question is: How can I register a thread scope for the session scope in my `@Scheduled` method?

I have tried something like this: `beanFactory.registerScope("session", new SimpleThreadScope());` but that also overrides the session scope of my webapplication :(

Comment: Scheduled tasks are performed on arbitrary threads. They have no logical connection to the session-scope, and so it makes no sense to try and do so.

Comment: I agree that there is no logical session-scope for scheduled tasks. Therefore it is acceptable to change the meaning of the session scope in the scheduled context from http-session-scope into another sort of 'session'-scope, like threadlocal or singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, this question is very much related to: [spring 3 scheduled task running 3 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672289/spring-3-scheduled-task-running-3-times). Since my ContextLoaderListener and DispatcherServlet were pointing at the same context config, the scopes got overridden. 
@skaffman/Wesley: Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Scheduled tasks have nothing to do with the sessionscope, the session may be even terminated by the time the scheduled task get executed. If you scheduled task requires data from the session, just pass a new object containing the data to the scheduled method.

Comment: The existing source has some 50+ references to session scoped objects. For now, I consider it unacceptable to manually pass in all those 'session' objects.