# How can I get Authentication().getPrincipal() in a Schedule method? - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I wanna run a schedule method and in this method I need to use information about user is logged in. However, when I run getPrincipal() my code gets nullPointException

```
@Component
public class Import extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private ActivityRepository activityRepository;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)
    public void importActivities() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        Principal principal = (Principal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        List<Activity> lastActivity = activityRepository.findFirstByOrderByStartDateDesc();

        int lastEpoch = 0;
        if (lastActivity.isEmpty() == false) {
            lastEpoch = (int) (lastActivity.get(0).getStartDate().getTime() / 1000);
        }
        System.out.println(lastEpoch);
        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBearerAuth(getAccessToken(principal));
        final HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
        ResponseEntity<List<Activity>> rateResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
                "https://www.strava.com/api/v3/athlete/activities?after=" + lastEpoch, HttpMethod.GET, entity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Activity>>() {
                });
        List<Activity> activities = rateResponse.getBody();

        activityRepository.saveAll(activities);
    }

    private String getAccessToken(final Principal principal) {

        final OAuth2Authentication oauth2Auth = (OAuth2Authentication) principal;
        final OAuth2AuthenticationDetails oauth2AuthDetails = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails) oauth2Auth.getDetails();

        return oauth2AuthDetails.getTokenValue();
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: I think it's scope is not request scope or session scope. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549909/spring-session-scoped-objects-in-scheduled.

Comment: Why you need to get principal, as it is not related to any session or request. Any use case you have to explain its requirement?

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumarLalasangi. I need to consume a restful using oAuth2 authentication in a schedule method. Do you have any suggestion or other way to do this?

Comment: Create a new user say `ApiAdmin` and hard code that principal. Or any other user which you prefer.